# Windows Server 2019 Bluetooth Headset Hands Free Not Working

Tags: bluetooth, headphones, headset, windows-server-2019, voice

Boundary Conditions:

- **Computer Make and Model:** Acer V3-772G Laptop
- **Operating System:** Windows Server 2019 Standard (Microsoft Windows Server Version 1809 OS Build 17763.1852)
- **Bluetooth Adapter:** Asus USB-BT500 (the laptop's Bluetooth adapter is disabled in Device Manager)
- **Headset:** Sennheiser HD 450BT

When pairing the headset to the system, in Bluetooth Settings only shows the headset as "Connected Music" ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVDlP.png)), and in the Device Manager only the "HD 450BT Stereo" is shown ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqcBB.png)). However, when using my company's laptop (Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise version 1809 OS build 17763.1577) with the same headset, in Bluetooth Settings I get "Connected Voice, Music" ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uO2VY.png)) and in the Device Manager two devices show up: "Headphones (HD 450BT Stereo)" and "Headset (HD 450BT Hands-free)" ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mn0tV.png)).

As a result, I can't use the mic on my Windows Server computer, whereas on my company laptop the mic works fine. All drivers are up to date and have been reinstalled multiple times. Any help is appreciated as I ran out of ideas.

**Edit:** Is there any limitation on Windows Server 2019 for using the Hands-free Profile (HFP) for Bluetooth headsets? As far as I have seen in Microsoft documentation, the Advanced Audio Distribution profile (A2DP) and the A/V Remote Control profile (AVRCP) (both of which work in both laptops) are part of the Wireless Application Protocol (WAP) Kernel Mode Driver, whereas the Hands Free profile (HFP) and Headset profile (HSP) (which do not work in my Windows Server laptop) are part of the Audio Kernel Mode Driver. Could this part of the Windows Bluetooth Stack be missing in Windows Server 2019? ([Bluetooth Driver Stack](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/bluetooth/bluetooth-driver-stack) description from Microsoft Docs.)

Comment: Same here! any update @Alejandro?

Comment: @Sakher No updates so far, but I will try to verify this on a different hardware to see if it is a hardware or driver issue, or if it really is a Windows Server 2019 problem.

Answer (score 1):

By modifying and importing drivers of bthhfenum.inf and wdma_bt.inf, which exclusively only support windows desktop version (amd64...1), I could enable the Hand-free devices like the desktop win10, and it shows 'Connected Voice, Music', but the microphone still does not work (surprisingly the hand-free output was fine). I checked this post https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-server-for-it-pro/bluetooth-and-wireless-display-not-working-on-windows-server/m-p/2223394/emcs_t/S2h8ZW1haWx8dG9waWNfc3Vic2NyaXB0aW9ufEwyUlZBWE1GQTYzMzJJfDMzMTExOTR8U1VCU0NSSVBUSU9OU3xoSw
and installed some service and reg keys but still not working.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I remember trying also to modify the drivers from the desktop Windows 10 but to no avail, at least you got some progress, thanks for reporting!